# Python "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable" while calling lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, typeerror

I have this function (reported in a simplified version without many **if**:

```
def get_marginals(marginals):
    marginal_dist = []

        if marginals == 'gaussian':
            marginal_dist.append(
                lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.ppf(x)) 
           
        elif marginals == 'student':
            marginal_dist.append(
                lambda x: scipy.stats.t.ppf(x))
  
    return marginal_dist
```

Now I would like to select the function based on the input:

```
    mgnl = get_marginals('gaussian')
```

My expectation is that **mgnl** is the lambda `lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.ppf(x)` but unfortunately when I call, for example, `mgnl(0.5)` I receive the following error:

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`

edit:
Please note that marginals can be a list.

Comment: What is `x` exactly?

Comment: @alec_djinn a number or an array of numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_marginals(marginals):
    marginal_dist = []
    if marginals == 'gaussian':
        marginal_dist.append(
            lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.ppf(x)) 
    elif marginals == 'student':
        marginal_dist.append(
            lambda x: scipy.stats.t.ppf(x))
    return marginal_dist

mgnl = get_marginals('gaussian')
```

All your code is good:

When you call `mgnl` you will get:

```
[<function __main__.get_marginals.<locals>.<lambda>(x)>]
```

To pass a value you need to take it out of list:

So, it will be:

```
mgnl[0](0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a list with your lambda function inside of it. Just return the lambda function, so:

```py
def get_marginals (marginals):
    if marginals == 'gaussian':
        return lambda x: scipy.stats.norm.ppf(x)   
    elif marginals == 'student':
        return lambda x: scipy.stats.t.ppf(x)
```

Comment: Or even just `return scipy.stats.norm.ppf` and `return scipy.stats.t.ppf`